# Destroy instance of class then create instance of it again

Tags: java, swing, components, awt

i have a class (Class ButtonX) that contains a button

when user clicks the button, it will create instance of the class `DialogX`

when I create instance of the class `DialogX` it will show up `JDialog`

```
  public class ButtonX {

    public ButtonX() {
        JFrame me = new JFrame();
        JButton n = new JButton("show dialog");
        n.addActionListener(ListenerX.listen);
        me.getContentPane().add(n);
        me.pack();
        me.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String[]args){
        new ButtonX();
    }
}
```

listener of that `JButton`

```
    public class ListenerX {
    public static ActionListener listen = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DialogX dialogx = null;
            dialogx = new DialogX();
        }};
}
```

class that contains `JDialog`

```
 public class DialogX {
    static JDialog g = new JDialog();
    public DialogX() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("label");
        g.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        g.getContentPane().add(label);
        g.pack();
        g.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        g.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

what I try to achieve is, that when user clicks the button, it will destroy instance of class `DialogX` ( if it exist ) and then create again instance of `DialogX`

What to do?

thanks..

forgive my english..

Comment: What is your question

Comment: @GuillaumePolet i need to create a fresh instance of JDialogX every time user click the button.. but according to my post code, (i think) its not create a fresh instance.. showed by JDialog must always have 1 JLabel on it but it doesn't.. JDialog always add again a new JLabel everytime user click the button..

Comment: Remove the `static` in front of `JDialog g = new JDialog();`

Comment: @GuillaumePolet thanks a lot it work ^^ .. but can i use it with static? because i need to rearrange topology of my class T-T if i remove the static.. but its ok if the only way is to remove the static.. just if theres another way.. ~_~

Comment: Yes you could do it differently but, usually, the use of `static` is the sign of a bad design or a poor understanding of programming concepts. `static` is the root of all evil in Java (except for constants), so try to stay away as much as you can.

Comment: thanks for the advice.. now i realy understand "static is the root of all evil in Java".. when i work this app i just in hurry with deadline of college task.. so i use the evil.. did the way to continue this project (still with static)  is to force garbage collector to clean it? if it yes,i choose to remove the static.. but if there another way.. how?

Comment: The use of `static` will actually prevent the Garbage Collector from clean that reference. `static` often leads to Memory Leaks (hence it is the root of evil). I can only recomend you to read more about the meaning of the `static`keyword

Comment: its ok.. thanks for already help..

Answer (score 4):

You cannot explicitly destroy objects in Java. Once there are no more references (think of pointers) to an Object left, it will be marked as eligible for being garbage collected. Your code therefore is *almost* fine, as it removes the old reference to the DialogX instance and creates a new one.
What you need to do is either extend `JDialog` with your DialogX class (then you can delete the JDialog variable completely) or remove the `static` keywoard before the JDialog variable `g`. Then you can call `dialogx.dispose()` (you extended JDialog) or a custom method you need to implement which forwards the call to `g.dispose()` (you did not extend JDialog).

Comment: No need to extend `JDialog` since you are not adding behaviour to it. Dropping the `static` keyword is enough, but that had already been said.